# zk LongUIOperation Executions.deactivate null pointer exception

Tags: multithreading, tomcat8, zk

I'm using LongUIOperation custom implementation, but, sometimes, on

```
Executions.deactivate(getNativeDesktop());
```

I receive messagebox on screen and:

> dic 11, 2017 11:09:42 AM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl handleError
>   GRAVE: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.notifyAttributeAssigned(Request.java:1528)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1514)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:540)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.ExecutionImpl.setAttribute(ExecutionImpl.java:497)
>   at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.Utils.getComponentInfos(Utils.java:120) at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.Utils.setComponentInfo(Utils.java:129) at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractUiFactory.newComponent(AbstractUiFactory.java:137)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:919)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:889)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:776)
>   at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.access$800(UiEngineImpl.java:128)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl$TemplateImpl.create(UiEngineImpl.java:2318)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.bind.impl.BindListitemRenderer.render(BindListitemRenderer.java:79)
>   at org.zkoss.zul.Listbox$Renderer.render(Listbox.java:2769) at
>   org.zkoss.zul.Listbox.doInitRenderer(Listbox.java:2584) at
>   org.zkoss.zul.Listbox.onInitRender(Listbox.java:2537) at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2366.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3146)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3077)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1846)
>   at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1618)
>   at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.endUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1222)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zkex.ui.comet.CometServerPush.deactivate(CometServerPush.java:522)
>   at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl.deactivateServerPush(DesktopImpl.java:1596)
>   at org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions.deactivate(Executions.java:1011) at
>   com.ims.web.ui.GenericViewModel.deactivateNativeDesktop(GenericViewModel.java:193)
>   at
>   com.ims.web.zk.ui.DesktopVMLongUIOperation.run(DesktopVMLongUIOperation.java:186)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Use case example:

```
@Command    
@Override
public void editBaseItem() throws Exception {
    super.editBaseItem();
    if(selectedBaseItem.getOid() == null){
        initNewItem();
    }
    final String sessionID = getSessionID();
    final StaffDailyAvailabilityVM instanceVM = this;
    new DesktopVMLongUIOperation(this,win,Labels.getLabel("def.msg.refreshdata","Refresh data...")) {
        @Override
        protected void execute() throws InterruptedException {
            try {
                StaffDailyAvailabilityManager.evaluateStaffDailyAvailabilitySynch(selectedBaseItem, sessionID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e,e);
            }
        }

        protected void onCleanup() {
            try {
                //refresh clock time list
                selectedBaseItem.getLastStaffDailyTimestampDTO();
                if(selectedBaseItem.isErrorDetected()){
                    selectedBaseItem.setCertified(false);
                }
                BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, instanceVM.getSelectedBaseItem(),"lastStaffDailyTimestampDTO");
                BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, instanceVM, "selectedBaseItem");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e,e);
            }
        };

    }.start();
}
```

Here the code:

public abstract class DesktopVMLongUIOperation implements Runnable {
    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DesktopVMLongUIOperation.class);
    private Thread thread;
    private AtomicBoolean cancelled = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private Window win;
    private GenericViewModel genericViewModel;

```
public DesktopVMLongUIOperation(GenericViewModel genericViewModel){
    this(genericViewModel,null,"");
}

public DesktopVMLongUIOperation(GenericViewModel genericViewModel, Window win, String busyMsg){
    this.win = win;
    this.genericViewModel = genericViewModel;
    try {
        this.genericViewModel.enableServerPush(null);
        if(win != null){
            Clients.showBusy(win,busyMsg);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e,e);
    }
}

/**
 * asynchronous callback for your long operation code
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
protected abstract void execute() throws InterruptedException;

/**
 * optional callback method when the task has completed successfully
 */
protected void onFinish() {};
/**
 * optional callback method when the task has been cancelled or was interrupted otherwise
 */
protected void onCancel() {};
/**
 * optional callback method when the task has completed with an uncaught RuntimeException
 * @param exception
 */
protected void onException(RuntimeException exception) {
    logger.error(exception,exception);
};
/**
 * optional callback method when the task has completed (always called)
 */
protected void onCleanup() {};

/**
 * set the cancelled flag and try to interrupt the thread 
 */
public final void cancel() {
    try {
        cancelled.set(true);
        if(thread != null){
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.error(e,e);
    }
}

/**
 * check the cancelled flag
 * @return
 */
public final boolean isCancelled() {
    return cancelled.get();
}

/**
 * Checks if the task thread has been interrupted. Use this to check whether or not to exit a busy operation in case.  
 * @throws InterruptedException when the current task has been cancelled/interrupted
 */
protected final void checkCancelled() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        if(Thread.currentThread() != this.thread) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this method can only be called in the worker thread (i.e. during execute)");
        }
        boolean interrupted = Thread.interrupted();
        if(interrupted || cancelled.get()) {
            cancelled.set(true);
            throw new InterruptedException();
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.error(e,e);
    }
}

/**
 * launch the long operation
 */
public final void start() {
    try {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.error(e,e);
    }
}

@Override
public final void run() {
    try {
        try {
            checkCancelled(); //avoid unnecessary execution
            execute();
            checkCancelled(); //final cancelled check before calling onFinish
            genericViewModel.activateNativeDesktop();
            logger.error("ACTIVATE: RUN");
            onFinish();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            try {
                cancelled.set(true);
                genericViewModel.activateNativeDesktop();
                logger.error("ACTIVATE: INTERRUPT");
                onCancel();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("interrupted onCancel handling", e1);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                logger.error(e1,e1);
            } finally {
                try {
                    genericViewModel.deactivateNativeDesktop();
                    logger.error("DEACTIVATE: INTERRUPT");
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    logger.error(e1,e1);
                }
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException rte) {
            try {
                genericViewModel.activateNativeDesktop();
                logger.error("ACTIVATE: EXCEPTION");
                onException(rte);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("interrupted onException handling", e1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e,e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    genericViewModel.deactivateNativeDesktop();
                    logger.error("ACTIVATE: EXCEPTION");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e,e);
                }
            }
            throw rte;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e,e);
        } finally {
            try {
                genericViewModel.deactivateNativeDesktop();
                logger.error("DEACTIVATE: RUN");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e,e);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            genericViewModel.activateNativeDesktop();
            logger.error("ACTIVATE: CLEANUP");
            try {
                if(win != null){
                    Clients.clearBusy(win);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e,e);
            }
            onCleanup();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("interrupted onCleanup handling", e1);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            logger.error(e1,e1);
        } finally {
            try {
                genericViewModel.deactivateNativeDesktop();
                logger.error("DEACTIVATE: CLEANUP");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e,e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And activate deactivate code from genericViewModel:

... ... public GenericViewModel(){ nativeDesktop = Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop(); }

... ...

```
public GenericViewModel(){
    nativeDesktop = Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop();
}

public boolean activateNativeDesktop() throws Exception{
    boolean res = false;
    if(getNativeDesktop() != null && getNativeDesktop().isAlive()){
        try {
            Executions.activate(getNativeDesktop());
            res = true;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error(e,e);
            throw(e);
        }
    }else{
        throw new Exception("ZK native Desktop is null");
    }
    return res;
}

public boolean deactivateNativeDesktop() throws Exception{
    boolean res = false;
    if(getNativeDesktop() != null && getNativeDesktop().isAlive()){
        try {
            Executions.deactivate(getNativeDesktop());
            res = true;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error(e,e);
            throw(e);
        }
    }else{
        throw new Exception("ZK native Desktop is null");
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your question to make it more readable. And then remove all lines that are not necessary to reproduce the problem. This is way too much stuff to read, understand and execute myself. It would be best if you came up with a small zul that we can copy/paste. Another thing: what zk version are you using?

Comment: I use zk 8.0.4 we will try to semplify posted code

Comment: The key point is 

> org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:540) at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.ExecutionImpl.setAttribute(ExecutionImpl.java:497) at 

`setAttribute()` is Java EE standard API, you can check what condition might produce null pointer exception when setting an attribute.